# form textbox - keep focus during page load

Tags: forms, textbox, focus

On my homepage I have a form with a search textbox.  If you click on the input and start typing when the page in still loading, something steals the focus so you have to click back in the input textbox.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Do I need to find what is stealing the focus?

Comment: Can you show some HTML, JS, or the page on the internet?

Comment: "Do I need to find what is stealing the focus" Obviously. "Is there a way to prevent this from happening?" After finding what's causing it yes.

Comment: I just wondered if there was some code to force the focus to stay in an input, but if not I'll comment out everything bit by bit until I find it.  Its only happening IE.  How many times I have said that!

Comment: http://www.kirkleescollege.ac.uk/
Be gentle :)

Comment: Looks like its just the js on the course search box causing the problem in IE.  I'll have a play with JQuery plugins that do the same thing much better than I can.

Comment: ok loads of js to look through so instead offered a solution to locate the element that has focus.

Comment: Using you code helped me uncover the issue.  Its this plugin causing the issue: https://github.com/ono/clearable_text_field I'll have to look out for a replacement or maybe only call it after the page has loaded.

Comment: you are already calling it after the page has loaded. It can be fixed.  Can you show the code that's running it? It will be something like $('.something').clearableTextField();

Comment: actually i found it.  i'll just update my answer `$('#f input#livesearch').clearableTextField();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like one of your scripts is setting something to focus on load.

Put this at the bottom of your HTML right before `</body>`. Your console will show you the HTML of the item that is gaining focus.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() { // NB not document ready
    console.log($(':focus')[0]);
    // alert($(':focus')[0]); // if you don't know what console is
});
</script>
```

Hopefully there will be an ID in the element that you can search your script for, or enough clues to let you find what's being told to focus on load. Then you can remove/alter that line.

**Addendum**

It turns out this is the culprit

```
$('#f input#livesearch').clearableTextField();
```

That *clearable* function is only ever going to be required if the user uses that field, so let's make it contextual, i.e. only when it's given focus, make that function available. This should stop the naughty plugin stealing focus.

```
$('#f input#livesearch').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).clearableTextField();
});
```

It's generally best to write contextually - you'll find pages with dozens of binds and "live" events being set up on onload, but they are rarely used. If it's something that doesn't need to happen until the user does something or until you can tell a user is about to do something, write it that way.